# Hugin 2012 build fail on Gentoo

Tags: gentoo

My system is Gentoo amd64, up to date.

```
[I] dev-libs/boost
 Available versions:  1.49.0-r2 (~)1.52.0-r6(0/1.52) (~)1.53.0(0/1.53) [M](~)1.54.0(0/1.54) {debug doc icu mpi +nls python static-libs +threads tools PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_5 python2_6 python2_7 python3_1 python3_2 python3_3"}
 Installed versions:  1.53.0(10:17:32 PM 08/19/2013)(icu nls python threads -debug -doc -mpi -static-libs -tools PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_2 -python2_5 -python2_6 -python3_1 -python3_3")
 Homepage:            http://www.boost.org/
 Description:         Boost Libraries for C++
```

My `boost` is already compiled with `threads` USE flag.

But I still got this error when compiling `Hugin`.

```
../hugin_base/libhuginbase.so.0.0: undefined reference to `boost::thread::join()'
../hugin_base/libhuginbase.so.0.0: undefined reference to  boost::thread::start_thread()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Some people suggests downgrade `boost` to 1.47...but it is no longer in the portage.

Comment: This seems dated but might be helpful to you: http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-899582-start-0.html

Comment: Thanks @slm, that's exactly where I got the idea to downgrade boost. And because that was dated, the downgrade option is no longer viable :(

Comment: Builds ok for me with boost-1.49.0-r2.

Comment: Oh, that's good news. But the problem is that I cannot downgrade *boost* at all. The *boost* 1.53 depends on *glibc-2.17*, and *boost-1.49* depends on *glibc-2.15*. And downgrade *glibc* is prohibited.

Comment: I've just upgraded boost to 1.53 and my glibc is still at 2.15. Hugin built without issue (though a couple other packages didn't )-: ). Which is a bit strange since that error looks like a build script issue. Tried rebuilding boost?

Comment: ok...that's strange...i have tried to rebuild boost many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is caused by a problem in boost-1.5, the `include` directory is not remove, and causing the *Hugin* compiling script to use the wrong header file.

Manually remove the orphaned directory solve the problem.